# Session timeout issue in java MVC(Struts,Spring) web application

Tags: java, spring, session, jboss, struts2

We have been facing a session timeout issue for our java MVC(struts and spring) web application.below is the issue description.

**Issue Description :** The ssesion  expires soon  after login . approximately the session expire in 10-30 mins after login. below are the different levels we set idle timeout.

**SSO Idle Timeout**: min idle timeout - **1hr** , max idle timeout - **8hrs**

**Idle timeout in application code(in web.xml)** -  **2hrs**

**Idle timeout in JBoss application server(in jboss-web.xml)** :  default idle timeout - **30mins**

**Some extra details** : After login successful, the application opens in a new window.

so as the SSO default idle timeout is 1hr ,the idle timeout in application's web.xml is 2hr, and the JBoss application server's default idle timeout is 30mins, why the session expires in 10-30mins after login ? please help us...

Comment: `why the session expires in 10-30mins after login ?` : `JBoss application server's default idle timeout is 30mins`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set session timeout in your code `httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(time_in_seconds);`
Actually do you use cookies?

Comment: i used httpsession to store user data